Seeking Assistance on Achieving Determinism in OpenAI GPT-4 Models
I’m currently working on a project that requires generating 100% reproducible outputs from OpenAI’s GPT-4 model for the same input prompt. Despite experimenting with various parameters like temperature, top_p, max_tokens, and setting a seed, I have not been able to achieve complete determinism.
Despite these efforts, there are still slight variations in the outputs. I understand that some level of stochasticity is inherent in these models, but I’m looking for any additional tips, tricks, or best practices that might help me achieve more consistent results.
Has anyone in the community successfully managed to get fully deterministic outputs from GPT-4? If so, could you please share your approach or any insights that might help?

I think what you are looking for is the seed parameter.

This feature is in Beta. If specified, our system will make a best
effort to sample deterministically, such that repeated requests with
the same seed and parameters should return the same result.
Determinism is not guaranteed, and you should refer to the
system_fingerprint response parameter to monitor changes in the
backend.

So what you do is for the first request you come up with a random seed number.  Run the prompt and save the 'system_fingerprint' value from the response fields.
From that point onwards, if you run the same prompt with the same seed along with the rest of the request parameters it most likely will return the same result.
You know when the response is different when the response 'system_fingerprint' does not match the first prompt 'system_fingerprint'. When this happens, openai has updated there model.
